Using DevExpress LookUpEdit control
I use LookUpEdit control in my WPF application.
It works perfectly for searching where all items arranged in alphabetical order, with FilterCondition set to "Contains".
Can I update something to display at the beginning all item with "StartWith" condition and after that all items with "Contains" condition
<LookUpEdit 
    ItemsSource="{Binding …}"
    IsReadOnly="{Binding …}"
    ShowSizeGrip="False"
    AutoPopulateColumns="False"
    FilterCondition="Contains"
    FindMode="Always"
    SelectedItem="{Binding …}">

Thank you very much

I guess you can try to use SubstituteDisplayFilter event. In this case you can patch filter criteria before it's applying to an inner source.
Here is the GitHub example
